# Continue sequence

Tags: number-sequence, calculation-puzzle, sequence

Son asked such a task. Continue the number sequence

```
5, 7, 8, 12, 11....
```

The son is in the second grade. They studied the operations of addition, subtraction and multiplication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a pretty bad question to ask anyone you are trying to teach mathematics, but a best guess would be:

> $(5 + 3\times 0 = 5), $
>  $(7 + 5\times 0 = 7), $
>  $(5 + 3\times 1 = 8), $
>  $(7 + 5\times 1 = 12), $
>  $(5 + 3\times 2 = 11), $
>  $(7 + 5\times 2 = 17), $
>  $...$
>
>  If we index the sequence, say $a(n)$, starting at $a(0) = 5$ we can say
>
>  Let: $m = n\mod 2$
>  ($m$ is $1$ if $n$ is odd, and $0$ if $n$ is even)
>
>  $a(n) = m\times 7 + (1-m)\times 5 + (m\times 5 + (1-m)\times 3) \times \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$

I wonder if they were taught about "flooring" or modulo arithmetic too?

Comment: This is the same as...if we consider alternating sequences and find the next term. Here it would be 5,8,11 form the first with a diff. of 3 and the next one (7,12,__) with a diff of 5 thereby giving 17 as the next term

Comment: Maybe that is how they are meant to crack it, but it's very weak I think.

Comment: Well I doubt it is ...5, 7, 8, 12, 11, 9, 13, 15, 22, 21, ... - that is [this](https://oeis.org/A186005) :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the original sequence

5, 7, 8, 12, 11, ..

it seems like the odd-numbered values increase by three, and the even-numbered values increase by five. So I would extrapolate that the series would continue like this:

5, 7, 8, 12, 11, **17, 14, 22, 17, 27, 20** ..

Comment: ^vote with a note: I first took "odd-numbered values" to mean 5, 7 and 11 but then realized that it  meant odd-_position_ values.

Comment: I do not like this answer, as it breaks the sequence into two unique sequences, that do not rely on each other.

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to [Jonathan Allan’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/55134/19765#55135) (which was posted two hours earlier) but with a slightly different presentation.